# Desktop brige modify registry with Visual Studio

Tags: c#, uwp, desktop-bridge

I´m converting a WPF application into a UWP one using the Desktop Bridge.

When I use the Desktop App Converter to convert MSI, the Registry modifications that installer does, are also done by installing package APPX.

But when I generate the package throw Visual Studio, having a UWP project with application files inside Win32 folder, I  don´t know how to include Registry values.

If I modify Registry in C# during execution, first launch have problems because of these missing Registry values.

Is there any way to achieve this? Thanks you.

Comment: Why don't you do the modifications that installer does on first execution of your app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two approaches (DAC vs VS) are not mutually exclusive. You first run the DAC and then take the output of the Desktop App Converter (incl. the Registry.dat file which contains your registry modifications) and add this as content to your Visual Studio packaging project.

This [video](https://mva.microsoft.com/en-US/training-courses/developers-guide-to-the-desktop-bridge-17373?l=uuwDh4WhD_8306218965) helps explain some of the tooling concepts. Hope it helps.